# Connecting to database on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: java, database

I have written java web application (using jsp and servlet) and deployed it on elastic beanstalk server while it use database to collect Username and Password of Users'. On the other hand I have JavaFX desktop application which I want to use the same database I have created on elastic beanstalk for desktop application too. So my question is how can I connect JavaFx desktop application to database located on server? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you referring to the RDS service?

Comment: Exactly sir, I used RDS and mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to change the RDS instance settings to enable public accessibility, assign a public subnet group to the RDS instance and then assign specific VPC security groups to allow access to the RDS externally.

Beware that this exposes your RDS instance to the public internet and poses a significant security risk.

More info: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ModifyInstance.MySQL.html

Alternatively, you can create a VPN connection to an on-premise network and access the database server over the VPN while it remains not publicly accessible.

Comment: Thank you so much sir, I have found solution for my problem with help of you.